# Snippet of using of library for resuming an interrupted upload of file through HTTP for IE and Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, resume-upload, resumablejs

Could you please provide snippet of using client side WEB library (at your discretion, for Internet Explorer and Edge browsers) that is designed to introduce **fault-tolerance into the upload of large files through HTTP**. That is capable to **resume file uploading** from the previous point after network failure, not from scratch. There is library Resumable.js that provide such functionality but according to Resumable.js site:

> Resumable.js does not have any external dependencies other the HTML5 File API. This is relied on for the ability to chunk files into smaller pieces. **Currently, this means that support is limited to Firefox 4+ and Chrome 11+**

Please provide approach (similar to functionality of Resumable.js) that works with IE v11 and Windows 10 Edge?

Comment: You do know that asking for recommendations is off-topic on SO, don't you?

Comment: I reformulated question - I ask about providing snippet of using any code that will resolve this issue. Likely this will be reusing of existing code because independent solution will exceed the size that fits format of the site.